# Killing Adobe Acrobat Viewer Process to free pdf

Tags: vb.net

I have an app that uses a webbrowser window to view several types of documents.  One of those document types is a pdf file.  After viewing this file and selecting certain criteria in the form it is uploaded to a database.  What I would then like to do is more the file to a temp directory that I've already created.  Problem being is that a process is still holding that pdf even though I have removed the pdf from the webbrowser.  So apparently the problem is that adobe acrobat is running in the background and still retaining the file.

I did fix it.. but not in a way to my satisfaction.  Essentially I ran a shell script in the program and killed off AcroRD32.exe.  This frees the file and gives me the ability to move.  I really dislike having to do this.. not very elegant whatsoever.  Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: Better way. Find out what is locking the file....

Comment: the best explanation I can come up w/ is that adobe open in the processes when viewing a pdf.  The viewer never closes instantly.. I've searched for several hours and I'm by far not the only person, but I see no resolutions.